# Where is the World Editor Tool?

Tags: interface, blender-internal-render-engine

I was trying to complete an assignment for my Digital Graphics & Animation class, and found it awfully hard to find the World Editor. The instructions were ***very vague.*** The instructions only say, and I quote: *"Go to the World Editor. Checkmark Blend Sky."* If there is anyone who can help me with this inconvenience, I will be pleased! Thank you for taking time out of your day/night to help a person who couldn't find a building if he tried!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are in blender render:

[image]

Then in the **Properties Editor** click on the blue icon that looks like a golbe, that is the world editor, there you'll find **Blend Sky**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Near* the top right of the screen, there is a row of tools that you can select to modify or add on (to) your project. The first icon (that is connected) on the row is a camera. Exactly two spaces to the left is a blue sphere. That is the World Editor tool. (***EXTRA HELP***) *If you click on the "World" tab, it will have three strips of text that you can select from; and believe it or not, the middle text is Blend Sky.*

Hope this helped!